# Replace a String with a Match from a regex in Jekyll

Tags: regex, ruby, jekyll

I want to take any Youtube URL and parse out the "code" so that I can imbed or link to the video.

I manged to find the following Ruby:

```
module Jekyll
    module RegexFilter
      def replace_regex(input, reg_str, repl_str)
        re = Regexp.new reg_str
  
        # This will be returned
        input.gsub re, repl_str
      end
    end
  end
  
  Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::RegexFilter)
```

However I dont undersatnd how this does the replace? Id I use:

```
{% assign youtubecode = item.embed | replace_regex: '^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube(-nocookie)?\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|live\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$', '$6' %}
```

I expected it to retrieve the code as I am replacing the string with the `$6` match for the sixth match. Howver it just uses the match pattern as a literal and I get the text `$6`.

Comment: If there is Ruby `gsub` under the hood, then the replacement backreference syntax is a backslash + the Group ID, i.e. `\6`.

Comment: You sir are a genius! I could not find that documented anywhere! Please add it as an answer and I will mark it!

Comment: I have just been answering regex questions since 2015 almost every day... No need for another answer.